# how can I show the date and time a user has used a textarea (saved with local storage onclick)?

Tags: javascript, save, textarea, last-modified

I am working on a textarea that saves to local storage on a button press. It also displays a pop up alert when something is saved or the textarea is visited. I also want it to display the date it was last updated or modified. How do I do that?

Here is the code :

```
<textarea id="box" style="margin-    bottom: 4px; width: 250px; height:     20px">
</textarea>
<br />
<button id="save">Save</button>



<script type="text/javascript">//  check if "user" is in localStorage

if (localStorage["box"])
{
var user = localStorage["box"] ;
document.getElementById("box").    value = user ;
alert("Welcome Back.")
}
else
{
document.getElementById("box").    placeholder = "Type here..." ;
    console.log("user not found in    localStorage") }

//save entered gmail address
document.   getElementById("save").  addEventListener("click", function ()
{
    var user = document.    getElementById("box").value ;
    //localStorage["box"] = user ;
    localStorage.setItem("box",    box) ;
    alert("The text has been saved.   ") ;
    console.log("The text has been    saved")
    } , false);</script>
```

I've found how to display the last modified date using timestamp. Here :

```
            <script type="text/javascript">
               (function() {



try {

    (window.localStorage.getItem) /   / will throw in Firefox under some settings
} catch (e) {

    return; // quit because dom.   storage.enabled is false
    }



    var area = document.    querySelector('#ta');

  // place content from previous     edit
  if (!area.value) {

      area.value = window.  localStorage.getItem('value');

  }

  updateLog(false);



  // your content will be saved   locally
   document.querySelector('#ta').   addEventListener('keyup',   function() {

      window.localStorage.  setItem('value', area.value);

      window.localStorage.  setItem('timestamp', (new Date()).  getTime());

    updateLog(true);

  }, false);



  function updateLog(new_save) {

      var log = document.  querySelector("#ta-log");

      var delta = 0;

      if (window.localStorage.  getItem('value')) {

          delta = ((new Date()).  getTime() - (new Date()).  setTime(window.localStorage.getItem('timestamp'))) / 1000;

          if (new_save) {

              log.textContent = 'Saved.   ';

              setTimeout(function() {

                  log.textContent = '';

              }, 3000);

          } else {

              log.textContent = 'last   saved: ' + delta + 's ago';

          }

      }

   } })();
```

But instead of  minutes, seconds, and nanoseconds I want to show the actual date and time.

Ex. Turn 5:30:20 to Sun, September 22, 2013 5:59PM.

Any help?
Is it understandable?

Answer (score 0):

Try to save `stringify object` inside the `localstorage`.

```
var obj = { 'content': 'Textarea content is held here', 'time': Date.now() };

localStorage.setItem('box', JSON.stringify(obj));
```

To get it:

```
var box = localStorage.getItem('box');

box = JSON.parse(box);

// to get content: box.content
// to get time: box.time
```

Comment: Where exzactly do you place those codes? Before or after what?

Answer (score 0):

Create a 2nd localstorage variable to hold the date/time of the last update.

Comment: I dont know how to do that.